# sagemaker環境にてデプロイに失敗する

Tags: python, python3, aws, 機械学習

#### 前提

awsのsagemakerにて音響モデルを用いたTTSシステムを作っています。

#### 実現したいこと

sagemakerで音響モデルをデプロイしたいと考えています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

デプロイ時に下記のエラーが繰り返し発生します。

```
Please specify --force/-f option to overwrite the model archive output file.
See -h/--help for more details./.sagemaker/mms/models/model
ERROR - %s already exists.
```

#### 以下、デプロイ用コード

```
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.pytorch.model import PyTorchModel

role = get_execution_role()

pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='s3://sagemaker-alterly/model.tar.gz', 
                             role=role,
                             framework_version="1.3.1",
                             py_version="py3",
                             entry_point='inference.py')

predictor = pytorch_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.t2.2xlarge', initial_instance_count=1)
```

※entry_pointの推論コード：iference.py

```
import os
import time
import torch
import pyopenjtalk
from espnet2.bin.tts_inference import Text2Speech
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from espnet2.tasks.tts import TTSTask
from espnet2.text.token_id_converter import TokenIDConverter
import numpy as np

import argparse
import text_processing as texp
import os

import boto3

prosodic = True

model_dir = "model/"
vocoder_dir = "vocoder/"
CONTENT_TYPE = "text/plain"

train_config = "model/config.yaml"
model_file = "model/50epoch.pth"
# train_config=""
# model_file="

vocoder_tag = "parallel_wavegan/jsut_hifigan.v1"
# ボコーダを指定
vocoder_config = "vocoder/config.yaml"
vocoder_file = "vocoder/50epoch.pth"


def model_fn(model_dir):
    print(model_dir + "config.yaml")
    print(model_dir + "100epoch.pth")
    model = Text2Speech.from_pretrained(
        train_config=model_dir + "config.yaml",
        model_file=model_dir + "100epoch.pth",
        vocoder_tag=vocoder_tag,
        device="cpu",
        speed_control_alpha=1.0,
        noise_scale=0.333,
        noise_scale_dur=0.333,
    )

    return model


def input_fn(request_body, content_type=CONTENT_TYPE):
    input_data = "あいうえお"
    return input_data


def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    import torch
    import os
    import numpy as np

    x = "デモテキスト"

    # model, train_args = TTSTask.build_model_from_file(
    #         train_config,  model_file, "cuda"
    #        )

    token_id_converter = TokenIDConverter(
        token_list=model.train_args.token_list,
        unk_symbol="<unk>",
    )

    text = x
    if prosodic:
        tokens = texp.a2p(x)
        text_ints = token_id_converter.tokens2ids(tokens)
        text = np.array(text_ints)
    else:
        print("\npyopenjtalk_accent_with_pauseによる解析結果：")
        print(texp.text2yomi(x), "\n")

    # synthesis
    with torch.no_grad():
        start = time.time()
        data = model(text)
        wav = data["wav"]
        # print(text2speech.preprocess_fn("<dummy>",dict(text=x))["text"])
    rtf = (time.time() - start) / (len(wav) / model.fs)
    print(f"RTF = {rtf:5f}")

    if not os.path.isdir("generated_wav"):
        os.makedirs("generated_wav")

    # let us listen to generated samples
    from IPython.display import display, Audio
    import numpy as np
    #display(Audio(wav.view(-1).cpu().numpy(), rate=text2speech.fs))
    #Audio(wav.view(-1).cpu().numpy(), rate=text2speech.fs)
    np_wav = wav.view(-1).cpu().numpy()

    fs = 48000
    print("サンプリングレート", fs, "で出力します。")
    from scipy.io.wavfile import write
    samplerate = fs
    t = np.linspace(0., 1., samplerate)
    amplitude = np.iinfo(np.int16).max
    data = amplitude * np_wav/np.max(np.abs(np_wav))
    write("espnet/egs2/jsut/tts1/generated_wav/"+x +
          ".wav", samplerate, data.astype(np.int16))
    print("\n\n\n")

    # バケットへの接続
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('alterly-source')
    bucket.upload_file("espnet/egs2/jsut/tts1/generated_wav/" +
                       x + ".wav", "source/"+x+".wav")

    x = "exit"


input_object = input_fn("あいうえお", "text/plain")
model = model_fn(model_dir)
prediction = predict_fn(input_object, model)
```

以下のコマンドで実行

```
!inference.py
```

#### 補足情報

圧縮前のディレクトリ構造は下記です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

こちらをmodel.tar.gzに圧縮してs3に設置しています。

急ぎの案件のため、他サイトでも相談させてもらっています。
進捗があった際にはこちらにも共有いたします。
https://teratail.com/questions/j8ux53rs8n7v2t

対処方法をご存知の方がいましたら、ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
下記のコードの `flamework_version` と `py_version` で指定する値をそれぞれ修正したところ改善しました。

誤：

```
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='s3://sagemaker-alterly/model.tar.gz',
role=role,
framework_version="1.3.1",
py_version="py3",
entry_point='inference.py')
```

正：

```
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='s3://sagemaker-alterly/model.tar.gz',
role=role,
framework_version="1.12",
py_version="py38",
entry_point='inference.py')
```

コメント等いただいた方、お手数おかけして失礼しました。
誠にありがとうございました。